# Passing Querystring to XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, sharepoint-2010, query-string

I know it is probably an old question but is it possible to use XSLT to filter content based on URL querystring?

Here's my XSLT, basically showing a list of all quick links:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:param name="id"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                <tr id="group1">
                    <td class="ms-gb" colspan="99" style="border:none">
                        <a href="{@URL}">
                            <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
                            <span style="float:left;"><xsl:value-of select="@Title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to display dynamic content based on querystring from URL:

http://sitename.com?ID=123

Wonder how to pass the 123 into the XSLT?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Can I invite you to provide insights?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following:

```
<xsl:param name="id"/>
```

Please take note that query strings are set to lowercase so for example if you you have a query string called `UserID` it will be converted to `userid`

Comment: Hi @lem.mallari thank you for the reply. I still don't know how and what pass the URL to the xsl parameter? It doesn't pass to itself right?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't seem to understand the question. Have you tried adding the line I provided?

Comment: Yes I did, I added the line you provided and <xsl:value-of select="$id"/> to display the value. But it's not working, it didn't get any value. And I tested my other global param, they display values fine.